# How the square bracket is being used inside an object

Tags: javascript

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
```

Here is `[name]` that is inside the square bracket. I know what it's doing but I just want to know what was the logic under the hood to use this logic?

```
setFormFields({ ...formFields, [name]: value });
    console.log(formFields);
  };
```

If it's array destructuring why and how is it working and why not object destructuring and what is the reason behind using this logic?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `const { name, value } = event.target;` is object destructuring, pulling the `name` and `value` properties off of `event.target`;

While your second example looks the same, it's the opposite - instead of destructuring an object into variables you're *creating* a new object. Somewhere above that line, there's a variable called `name`.

You can think of the example like this:

```
const name = 'someKey';
const value = 'someValue';
const formFields = { keyOne: 'one' };

const newObject = { ...formFields, [name]: value }; // { keyOne: 'one', someKey: 'someValue' };
```